# Increasing intensity of RGB

Tags: android, image, image-processing

I am stuck in a problem and dont know where to look at.
I need to increase intensity of particular color in image, like R, G, or Blue.
When I am doing that, certain colors are not rendering properly.

Below is the image that I took for testing:
[image]

Now when I increase like Green color:

```
A = Color.alpha(p);
R = Color.red(p);
G = (int)(Color.green(p)*1.2);
B = Color.blue(p);
```

This is what I get:
[image]

What can be the solution to fix those Pink patches.

Thanks

Comment: Guessing you should clamp the G value  G=min(G,255)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ty clamping the values so that they don't go over 255. Like this:

```
A = Color.alpha(p);
R = Color.red(p);
G = Math.min((int)(Color.green(p)*1.2), 255);
B = Color.blue(p);
```

Comment: That worked, can't believe the answer was so simple. Thanks